# How can i solve this optimization problem effectively?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-equations, closed-form, numerical-optimization, iterated-function-system

Recently, i met an optimization problem

$$ \arg \min_{\mathbf{x}}\Vert \mathbf {Kx} - \mathbf{y} \Vert^2_2+\frac{\eta \Vert \mathbf{Dx} -\mathbf d \Vert_2^2 }{\Vert \mathbf{Dx} \Vert_2^2}  $$

from that, $\mathbf{K, D, y} $ are considered known, and dimensions are $ \mathbf x\in \mathcal R^{n \times 1}$, $ \mathbf K, \mathbf D\in \mathcal R^{m \times n}$, $\mathbf y\in \mathcal R^{m \times 1}$, respectively.

My question is, how can i solve this equation and get $\mathbf x$ effectively?

Attemptation 1:

$$ \arg \min_{\mathbf{x}}  \Vert \mathbf D \mathbf x \Vert^2_2 \cdot  \Vert \mathbf{Kx} - \mathbf{y} \Vert^2_2+{ \eta \Vert \mathbf{Dx} -\mathbf d \Vert_2^2 } $$

let $f(\mathbf x)$ be the object, and do the gradient,

$$ \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x} = 2 \mathbf D^\top \mathbf D \mathbf x \cdot \mathbf x^\top \mathbf K^\top \mathbf K \mathbf x + 2 \mathbf x^\top \mathbf D^\top \mathbf D \mathbf x \cdot \mathbf K^\top \mathbf K \mathbf x - 2 \mathbf D^\top \mathbf D \mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y^\top \mathbf {Kx} - 2\mathbf x^\top \mathbf D^\top \mathbf D \mathbf K^\top \mathbf y + 2 \mathbf y^\top \mathbf y \cdot \mathbf D^\top \mathbf D \mathbf x $$

Unfortunately, I'm unable to solve this problem with my current knowledge. Is there anyone who could provide me with some advice? (The person I asked for help couldn't offer any helpful ideas either.)

I would greatly appreciate it if you could recommend any textbooks or literature on this particular topic.

Comment: This problem seems to be a non-convex (especially the second component of your objective function).

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the use case of this problem definition?

Comment: @user550103 I'm attempting to utilize this model for some image processing tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}  \def\g{\gamma} \def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda} \def\s{\sigma} \def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bb{\b^{-\o}}
\def\bbb{\b^{-2}}
\def\BR#1{\,\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Rename the variables $(D,d)\to(A,b)\,$ so we don't confuse them with derivative operations, and define some auxiliary functions
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \frob{Ax-b}^2 &\qiq d\a = \BR{2A^T\LR{Ax-b}}^Tdx \\
\b &= \frob{Ax}^2 &\qiq d\b = \BR{2A^T Ax}^Tdx \\
\g &= \frob{Kx-y}^2 &\qiq d\g = \BR{2K^T\LR{Kx-y}}^Tdx \\
}$$
Use these to rewrite the objective function
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= \g + \eta\a\bb \\
df
 &= d\g + \eta\bb\,d\a - \eta\a\bbb\,d\b \\
 &= 2\BR{K^T\LR{Kx-y} + \eta\bb A^T\LR{Ax-b} -\eta\a\bbb A^T{Ax}}^Tdx \\
 &= 2\bb\BR{\b K^T\LR{Kx-y} +\eta A^T\LR{Ax-b} -\eta\a\bb A^T{Ax}}^Tdx \\
\grad fx
 &= 2\bb\BR{\b K^T\LR{Kx-y} +\eta A^T\LR{Ax-b} -\eta\a\bb A^T{Ax}} \\
}$$
Set this gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $x$ vector
$$\eqalign{
&\BR{\b K^TK +\LR{\eta-\eta\a\bb}A^TA}\:x \;=\; \LR{\b K^Ty + \eta A^Tb} \\
&x \:=\, \BR{\b K^TK +\LR{\eta-\eta\a\bb}A^TA}^{-1}\LR{\b K^Ty + \eta A^Tb} \\
}$$
This ***looks*** like a solution, but it's not since there are variables on the RHS that are functions of $x$. However, it does suggest the following iterative scheme
$$\eqalign{
&x_\o = \LR{K^TK}^{-\o}K^Ty \\
&{\rm repeat} \\
&\quad \a_k = \frob{Ax_k-b}^2 \\
&\quad \b_k = \frob{Ax_k}^2 \\
&\quad x_{k+\o} = \LR{\b_kK^TK +\LR{\eta-\eta\a_k\bb_k}A^TA}^{-\o}\LR{\b_kK^Ty + \eta A^Tb} \\
&\quad k=k+\o \\
&{\rm until\;\;converged}\\
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, the answer has been incredibly valuable to me. Additionally, I'd like to inquire about recommended courses or textbooks, from your perspective, that could effectively aid me in handling similar issues if they arise in the future.